# continue for loop even after a command within it exits

Tags: python, linux, shell

I am running a command(testcases) in a for loop. When a test step fails in a test case, it aborts the rest of the test steps and exits. Because of this my for loop also exits midway. I don't have control over how the tests behave but I want to continue to run the for loop for the rest of the test cases. How can I achieve this? As of now I dont have a return value for the command that is used to run the tests.

Update: Hello all, Thank you for your replies. Sorry I should have posted my code earlier. Here it is... I have written as shell script:

```
for file in `ls *.xml`; do
  testrunner.sh -j -a -f"output" $file
done
```

I will try the suggestions posted by you all and post my comments. Thanks

Comment: Please post this for loop?  Also, is `set -e` anywhere?  That's a usual culprit for this kind of thing.

Comment: Is this a python for loop or a shell for loop? A vague description combined with scattergun tagging makes this question very hard to answer.

Comment: if you're referring to a shell script loop, try running the cmd in parens to create a subshell that won't exit the whole loop (I think), i.e. `for program in x y z; do ($program) ; echo past $program ; done`. Good luck.

Comment: @zebediah49 except good scripting practice is to use `set -e` anyway. Better to do as @shellter suggested and run the loop body in a subshell.

Comment: checking e=$? helped me solve the issue. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by a common exits? If you mean it will throw an Exception, you could probably use `continue` within `try` and `except` block to make the for loop keep going after the Exception.

Example:

```
for i in range(1,10):
  print i
  try:
    if i == 4:
      raise NameError
  except NameError:
    continue
```

This code will print out 1 to 9 even if there is an Error raised at `i=4`.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the failed test is raising an exception.  You need to learn how exceptions work, and put a `try:` block around the test code to catch the exception and allow the script to continue.

Here's a web page you could study: http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/exceptions/